# GetLoginResultAsync send wrong message to client

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

it seems that AccountController (ABP 2.3 standard template version) send wrong message to client browser for instance when:

1. User type wrong credential ;
2. Username doesn't exist ;
3. User market as "inactive" ;

   ```
   switch (loginResult.Result)
   {
       case AbpLoginResultType.Success:
           return loginResult;
       default:
           throw CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt(loginResult.Result, usernameOrEmailAddress, tenancyName);
   }
   ```

For instance, **CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt** return UserFriendlyException exception when AbpLoginResultType.UserIsNotActive is true (user inactive) but the client recieve a generic "**An error has occurred! - Error detail not sent by server**" message instead the "friendly message"

```
private Exception CreateExceptionForFailedLoginAttempt(AbpLoginResultType result, string usernameOrEmailAddress, string tenancyName)
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case AbpLoginResultType.Success:
            return new ApplicationException("Don't call this method with a success result!");

        case AbpLoginResultType.InvalidUserNameOrEmailAddress:

            // Wrong Username/password
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("UnknownUser"));                                                    

        case AbpLoginResultType.InvalidPassword:
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("InvalidUserNameOrPassword"));
        case AbpLoginResultType.InvalidTenancyName:
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("ThereIsNoTenantDefinedWithName{0}", tenancyName));
        case AbpLoginResultType.TenantIsNotActive:
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("TenantIsNotActive", tenancyName));
        case AbpLoginResultType.UserIsNotActive:
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("UserIsNotActiveAndCanNotLogin", usernameOrEmailAddress));
        case AbpLoginResultType.UserEmailIsNotConfirmed:
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), "UserEmailIsNotConfirmedAndCanNotLogin");
        case AbpLoginResultType.LockedOut:
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"), L("UserLockedOutMessage"));
        default: //Can not fall to default actually. But other result types can be added in the future and we may forget to handle it
            Logger.Warn("Unhandled login fail reason: " + result);
            return new UserFriendlyException(L("LoginFailed"));
    }
}
```

i take a look at Log.txt file and found

WARN  2017-09-27 10:51:55,219 [8    ] MPA_EF.Web.Controllers.AccountController - Login failed!
Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException: Login failed!
   at BBWP_ABP_MPA_EF.Web.Controllers.AccountController.d__13.MoveNext() in C:_Ambienti\vs2015\Biosic\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\BBWP_ABP_MPA_EF.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 130
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BBWP_ABP_MPA_EF.Web.Controllers.AccountController.<Login>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\_Ambienti\vs2015\Biosic\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\BBWP_ABP_MPA_EF.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 100
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

**Edit**
no customization in Login method

[Standard Login method AccountController.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/f40231d544486a3a7c2585d54e838aa535cb4f80/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa/Controllers/AccountController.cs)

[Login method inside my project](https://pastebin.com/B5WB181u)

Comment: Hi Aaron,
no it's GetLoginResultAsync method inside AccountController

Comment: The login method inside controller call GetLoginResultAsync

Anyway tenants is disabled for this application

Comment: No, everything is "standard"

Comment: Yes
https://pastebin.com/B5WB181u

Comment: try @Richard Brink solution it should solve your problem

Comment: How do I handle the same in .Net Core 2.2 ABP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the provided log I see no issues with the processing of your code. The only thing I can think of is a configuration issue in your `web.config`.

Make sure the `<customErrors />` tag is set to either `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />` or `<customErrors mode="On" />`.

Comment: yes

For some strange reason I had changed the value in the web.config file, now works correctly.

It would be interesting to understand the round of code that led to the generic message being displayed

Comment: How do I handle the same in .Net Core 2.2 ABP?

Comment: .net core also have a webconfig file if not u can manually add one